# Increment Range Value by 1 in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to rename many worksheets from a worksheet that contains stock market codes. To do this I have the codes in a worksheet called Update. The codes are from A2 to A10. I have set up a For loop to goto the next activeworksheet and as the range value is increased, the worksheet gets renamed to the new cell value in the Update WSheet

The problem I have is that I want the Range value to increase by 1 which will select the next name for the worksheet. I have tried adding 1 to the Range value but did not work

```
Sub changeWSnames()
    Dim sheetname As Worksheet
    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 1 To 10
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(r).Activate
        Set sheetname = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        sheetname.Name = Worksheets("Update").Range("a2").Value 
    Next r

    r = r + 1
End Sub
```

What I need is too workout is how to increment the `.Range("a2").Value` , i.e.  to increase by `1`, example it becomes `Range("a3").Value` etc etc.

Comment: Don't use `.Activate` instead reference your sheet directly: `Set sheetname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(r)` and you don't need the `r = r + 1` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
sheetname.Name = Worksheets("Update").Range("a2").Value
```

with:

```
sheetname.Name = Worksheets("Update").Range("a" & (r+1)).Value
```

So the first time through the loop we use **a2**, the next time we use **a3**, etc.

Comment: Would it not be better just to start the `FOR` loop at **2**? That way you can just use **r** rather than **r+1**

Comment: @Zac  It **would** be better because you would be avoiding doing unnecessary math in the loop.

Comment: @Zac You can't just start the loop at 2 because you would bypass the first worksheet.